# ESP32-C3 wakes from deep sleep on GPIO. Can't determine GPIO Pin pressed

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm using an ESP32-C3. Here's the button part of my circuit:

[image]

I want it to wake from deep sleep on a GPIO button press.

It does wake successfully, but when I ask for the reason for waking, I get `ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_UNDEFINED` (i.e. 0), instead of `ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_GPIO` (i.e. 7)

Note that it does wake up from deep sleep, but gives the wrong reason.

```
// In setup:

pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
pinMode(4, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
pinMode(5, INPUT_PULLDOWN);

esp_sleep_source_t thecause = get_wakeup_cause();
printf("Woke up for reason: %d.\n", thecause);
// Prints:
// Woke up for reason: 0.

int GPIO_reason = esp_sleep_get_gpio_wakeup_status(); // If wakeup was caused by another source other than GPIO, this function will return 0.
printf("Getting GPIO Raw reason: %d\n", GPIO_reason); 
// Prints:
// Getting GPIO Raw reason: 0

esp_reset_reason_t resetreason = esp_reset_reason();
printf("resetreason: %d.\n", resetreason);
// Prints:
// resetreason: 1.
// ESP_RST_POWERON is 1. ESP_RST_DEEPSLEEP is 8. Should be 8, not 1.
```

Later on:

```
// Get ready to go into deep sleep.

// Have to use a pin <= GPIO 5 to wake from deep sleep via GPIO
printf("Pin 3 validity: %d\n\r", (int) esp_sleep_is_valid_wakeup_gpio((gpio_num_t) 3));
printf("Pin 4 validity: %d\n\r", (int) esp_sleep_is_valid_wakeup_gpio((gpio_num_t) 4));
printf("Pin 5 validity: %d\n\r", (int) esp_sleep_is_valid_wakeup_gpio((gpio_num_t) 5));
// Prints:
// Pin 3 validity: 1
// Pin 4 validity: 1
// Pin 5 validity: 1

// Now setting GPIO dead interrupts to wake from sleep.
 
  esp_err_t setdeepsleepresult = esp_deep_sleep_enable_gpio_wakeup(
      ((1ULL<<3) | (1ULL<<4) | (1ULL<<5))
      , ESP_GPIO_WAKEUP_GPIO_HIGH);
      // Note, my buttons are connected to high via a 1k resistor, when the button is pressed.
      
  printf("deepsleepresult was %d.\n", (int) setdeepsleepresult);
// Prints:
// deepsleepresult was 0.


  printf("Sleeping now\n");
  esp_deep_sleep_start();
```

So it looks like `esp_sleep_get_wakeup_cause()` is wrong. It should return ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_GPIO (which is 7), instead of ESP_SLEEP_WAKEUP_UNDEFINED (which is 0).

But more importantly, I can't find out which pin that was pushed that caused the wake up, from `esp_sleep_get_gpio_wakeup_status()`,  which is critical.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Works fine when waking on LOW on the devkit board. But on this custom PCB, the buttons go HIGH on press.

Comment: Update 2023-09-29: I'm using pulldown resistors in the above. Next, I'm going to try pullup, with the buttons instead connecting the pin to GND.